# Petition to unclose an adventureworks question

Tags: discussion

The question:

[Which version of AdventureWorks has a column called CustomerId on sales.vIndividualCustomer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106088/which-version-of-adventureworks-has-a-column-called-customerid-on-sales-vindivid)

It was closed as "too localized." Adventure Works is *THE* sample database for SQL Server.  The number of publicly released Adventure Works schemas fits in a `TINYINT`, and the answer to my question could be achieved by a simple but exhaustive search. I literally required one more step to come from the question to self answer. I think its a suitable question under the circumstances.

Comment: Even given all you've said, don't you think the question is "not relevant to most of our audience" simply by virtue of being specific to what I assume is a fairly old version of Studio?

Comment: If the question can be answered with a 'simple but exhaustive search' why didn't you search yourself but chose to ask us to do the work?

Answer (score 1):

The question has an accepted answer - what would reopening (allowing additional answers) achieve? Please edit your question to clarify - and perhaps unaccept the existing answer if appropriate. I'm not opposed to reopening it, but you need to make the case clearer.

Update: On reflection, I have decided to reopen the question so you can self-answer it. There's no real harm in doing so, and we can always close it again afterward if that is appropriate. I do still think it's odd that you have left the existing answer accepted though.

Update: As no new answer was forthcoming after a month of reopening, I have re-closed the question.